# get() returned more than one Product -- it returned 14

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am a student currently learning Django. When I register the product, I want to complete the product registration by specifying the product option, and I want to get the product_code of the option model from get. I wrote this code, but the get_object part keeps getting errors. There are currently 14 registered products, so I think there is an error like above, so please tell me how to solve it. I would appreciate it if you could let me know. I'd like to ask you very much.

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from zeronine.models import *
from .forms import ProductForm, OptionForm

# Create your views here.

def product_upload(request):
    current_category = None
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    products = Product.objects.all()
    slug = Product.slug

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ProductForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():
            product = Product()
            product.name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            product.benefit = form.cleaned_data['benefit']
            product.detail = form.cleaned_data['detail']
            product.target_price = form.cleaned_data['target_price']
            product.start_date = form.cleaned_data['start_date']
            product.due_date = form.cleaned_data['due_date']
            product.category_code = form.cleaned_data['category_code']
            product.image = request.FILES['image']
            product.username = request.user
            product.slug = slug
            product.save()

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = OptionForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            option = Option()
            option.name = form.cleaned_data['option_name']
            option.product_code = get_object_or_404(Product)
            option.save()

            return render(request, 'zeronine/list.html',
                          {'form': form, 'current_category': current_category, 'products': products, 'categories': categories, 'slug': slug})

    else:
        form = ProductForm()

    return render(request, 'product/product_upload.html', {'form': form, 'current_category': current_category, 'products': products, 'categories': categories})
```

Comment: Which product do you try to get here: `get_object_or_404(Product)`? Obviously you haven't passed any parameters so there won't be any filtering and you will get multiple rows.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Thank you for your warm reply. I'm currently trying to get an option while registering the product. I'd like to get the product_code of the product I'm registering at the same time as I specify the option, so how can I get the code of the product I'm registering now?

Comment: You already have the variable `product` in that case, no need to fetch it from the database, just write `option.product_code = product`.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I solved the problem that I couldn't solve for a few hours. Thank you so much. Are you a coding genius?